Delphi 12 Android 13: App crash on starting Service
The App has always working perfectly, but now I upgraded to Delphi 12, many things no longer seem to work.
I now find that the complete App crashes as soon as I start the Foreground Service. Previousely this worked perfectly.
I have no idea what is happening.
The Android Log has pages of stuff, but the Errors I get are these:
// TAndroidHelper.Context.startService(GetIntent('com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService'));

2024/08/19 08:38:26.162 I   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   info    SARTrack Client: [C] [08:38:26.154] isServiceStarted...
2024/08/19 08:38:26.173 I   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   info    SARTrack Client: [C] [08:38:26.166] isServiceStarted: TRUE

Then lots of stuff marked Error:
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp ----- class 'Lcom/embarcadero/services/SARTrackServiceProxyInterface;' cl=0x12c15918 -----
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp objectSize=188 (172 from super)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp access=0x0000.0001
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp interfaces (1):
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 0: java.lang.Class<java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler> (cl=0x0)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp vtable (4 entries, 11 in super):
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 0: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.CreateProxyClass(java.lang.Class, long)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 1: void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.cleanNative(long)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 2: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative2(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], long)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 3: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[])
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp direct methods (1 entries):
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 0: void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.<init>()
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp instance fields (1 entries):
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp 0: long com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.pointer
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 E   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp Failed to register native method com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; in /data/app/~~Fp6XJtxT5BQ_Ek-WC7J9rw==/nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp-kHH5upNo6s_PgHGit_wdsw==/base.apk
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI RegisterNatives called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/embarcadero/services/SARTrackServiceProxyInterface;.dispatchToNative(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;"

Then pages of Fatal:

2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:-2)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreate(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:51)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService.onCreate() (SARTrackService.java:41)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:5073)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2024/08/19 08:38:26.383 F   nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp 32317   32317   ack.SARTrackApp java_vm_ext.cc:591] at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:2428)

etc. Anybody can give me an idea what is going on?

Update: Based on other reports, I also deleted all .java files in the Appdata Embarcadero area, and they where regenerated. But it made no difference in this case.

Don't use comments to add details - edit your question instead. Also define the "language" for the code formatting to avoid the wrong one being chosen. And use quotation formatting. Have you even noticed that your own text is now shown as code, too?

The answer is still the same as a long time ago:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidServiceDelphi111

Link-only answers are bad - include an actual solution by citing to what you link to.
